# TCP doesn't ACK every other segment

Tags: tcp

I am reading [Stevens 1993], in the chapter of TCP Bulk Data, shows the "ACK every other segment "strategy, but after that, he gives a figure like this:

(Sorry for the low quality picture, I don't know how to upload high resolution picture)

[image: Figure]

**The segment 8 ACKed 4 segments, doesn't that conflict with "ACK every other segment" ?** And I am sure it's nothing about OS, because the author use same machines in two examples.

Also I looked up [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) which also indicate that

> .....in a stream of full-sized segments there SHOULD be an ACK for at
> least every second segment.

Comment: @RyanVincent No I don't mean I see 8 segments, it's the eighth segment acks segment 4, 5, 6, 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux will ACK every other full segment, actually two times MSS worth of data and wait mostly MAX_DELAY before doing so. It was made configurable back in 2012: https://lwn.net/Articles/502585/

The delayed ACK can be turned off with the TCP_QUICKACK socket option. (For the next ACK)

It looks like most Windows versions ACK less often, not sure if this is controlable.

I suspect in the illustration he was assuming a slow sender which either does not follow the every-other SHOULD because it was so slow processing the incoming requests that the receiver was simply seeing the other outstanding data when it came around to acknowledge them (or he was not paying attention to this detail). It surely is acknowledging only 4*mss which happens to be the RWin.

Comment: I guess your suspicion is the reason. The only reasonable explanation so far.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you could send an ACK for every PSH/ACK. I guess if you want to use bulk data the point is to only ACK every window (which is necessary to slide the window forward).

Comment: Here the figure do only ACK every window, and it's possible to ack for every segment, but the author says it should ACK every other segment while in this figure it acked 4 segments atone time, I just got confused.

Comment: I think you actually must ack all pushes which really makes things bad if they are frequent.

Answer (score 0):

Steven mentions that "ACK every other segment" is **very common**. It is not a MUST. To quote him from the same chapter you referred :

> "With TCP's sliding-window protocol the receiver **does not have to
>   acknowledge** every received packet. With TCP, the ACKs are
>   cumulative-they acknowledge that the receiver has correctly received
>   all bytes up through the acknowledged sequence number minus one"

Comment: Yeah I read that. But how to explain RFC's ".....in a stream of full-sized segments there SHOULD be an ACK for at least every second segment". And I think here Stevens means doesn't have to acknowledge every packet, instead of doesn't have to "ack every other segment ", after all,  "ack every other segment" exactly allows us to not ack for every packet. The latter is essential to the former.

Answer (score 0):

So, since there is no correct answer. I made some tests.

1. From CentOS 7 to OS X 10.12 through Ethernet, round-trip time 10ms :

   The TCP ACK at least every third segment.
2. From FreeBSD 10.1 to OS X 10.12 through WAN, round-trip time 100ms:

   The FreeBSD sends an ACK for at least every second segment, just as RFC
   mentioned.

Still can't explain the problem. 
What clear is that it seems most implementations do have a maximum number of segments between two adjacent acks, though every implementation may got their own value.